# Android google map overlay on top

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, overlay

I added an overlay image to google map, but the image not above the map, I can still see the street name, icon ...
How can I make the overlay over the map or remove street name, icon...?
[image]

Comment: I tried setting zIndex of GroundOverlay but it's not work

Comment: did you get this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [style your map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) to hide labels:

```
googleMap.setMapStyle(
        MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                this, R.raw.style_json));
```

**style_json.json**

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: it is ok but i need to hide lablels only above the image not the entire map. is it possible? any hint?